# My Wordpress Site Refused to Connect after I increase WP_Memory_Limit

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

recently i edit my site "wp-config.php" to increase the "wp_memory_limit" and restart the server. But, after i restart the server i cant access the site, connection refused, i restore the "wp-config.php" to original state but still connection refused, any idea how to solve my problem? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PHP memory limit on the server; if you are using the latest version of wordpress you can check from the site health information whether it's low or has sufficient memory; Check logs from the directory.

First option is; You can increase the memory by upgrading the website’s hosting plan.
Second option is  [Using an FTP Client to Access Your Site’s Files](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-memory-limit/#using-an-ftp-client-to-access-your-sites-files). Please check those options and if you are still facing an issue; will try with other troubleshooting methods.